# How to highlight an editable word in dynamically generated text?

Tags: javascript, html, css

#### Intro

I am creating a content editor in which I want to add the functionality to choose a word which you would like to be highlighted while typing your content.

At this moment I achieved to search any word chosen in the `#dynamicWord` and then typed in #contentAreaContainer and give it a red border by adding *em* around the keyword and style the *em* trough CSS:

#### Part of the Code:

```
<div class="word">
      Dynamic word to highlight: <input name="dynamic_word" id="dynamicWord" value="Enter word..">
</div>

<div id="contentAreaContainer" oninput="highlighter()">
    <textarea id="contentArea"></textarea>
</div>
```

---

```
function highlighter()
{
var contentAreaContainer = document.getElementById('contentAreaContainer');
var dynamicWord = document.getElementById('dynamicWord').value;
wrapWord(contentAreaContainer, dynamicWord);
};
```

wrapWord() does:

```
function wrapWord(el, word)
{
var expr = new RegExp(word, "i");
var nodes = [].slice.call(el.childNodes, 0);
for (var i = 0; i < nodes.length; i++)
{
    var node = nodes[i];
    if (node.nodeType == 3) // textNode
    {
        var matches = node.nodeValue.match(expr);
        if (matches)
        {
            var parts = node.nodeValue.split(expr);
            for (var n = 0; n < parts.length; n++)
            {
                if (n)
                {
                    var em = el.insertBefore(document.createElement("em"), node);
                    em.appendChild(document.createTextNode(matches[n - 1]));
                }
                if (parts[n])
                {
                    el.insertBefore(document.createTextNode(parts[n]), node);
                }
            }
            el.removeChild(node);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        wrapWord(node, word);
    }
  }
}
```

---

```
em{border: 1px solid red;}
```

#### The problem:

Now at this moment every time on input in #contentAreaContainer the keyword chosen is highlighted a short period in the #contentAreaContainer, because `highlighter()` is triggered on input. But it should stay highlighted after finding it instead of only oninput.

1. I need oninput to search for the #dynamicWord value with `wrapWord()` while some one is typing;
2. Any time the #dynamicWord value was found it should permanently get an *em*

So how can I sort of 'save' the found keywords and permanently give them the  element until the dynamic keyword gets edited?

Check the **[DEMO version](http://dynamicword.voogd-wd.nl/)**

#### Solved:

Using `setTimeout()` instead of oninput I managed to make the highlight look constant. The change:

```
function highlighter()
{
var contentAreaContainer = document.getElementById('contentAreaContainer');
var mainKeyword = document.getElementById('main_keyword').value;
wrapWord(contentAreaContainer, mainKeyword);
repeater = setTimeout(highlighter, 0.1);
}
highlighter();
```

I removed `oninput="highlighter()"` from `#contentAreaContainer`.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to highlight words in a textarea. As far as I know a textarea does not support html elements inside. If you do it would simply display them as text.

Therefore you need to use an editable div. This is a normal div but if you add the attribute:

```
contentEditable="true"
```

the div acts like a textarea with the only difference it now process html elements. I also needed to change the onchange event into the onkeyup event. The editable div does not support onchange events so the highlight would not be triggered. The HTML for this div looks like:

```
<div contentEditable="true" id="contentArea">Test text with a word in it</div>
```

Here is the working code in a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Q6bGJ/ When you enter a new character in the textarea your keyword gets highlighted.

However there is still a problem left. You surround the keyword with an em element. This results in surrounding it on every keystroke. Now you end up width many em's around the keyword. How to solve this, I leave up to you as a challenge.

Comment: I'm using codemirror to make a 'fake' textarea so I can put HTML elements inside. I already managed to solve the problem by using setTimeout instead of using oninput! Thanks for your answer. I'll update my post.

Comment: Ok, next time you ask a question please mention as completely as possible what you use. Now I have spend time on finding a solution for you while you were using another library. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for the advice, I'll do that next time!